# Sorted element container which can be accessed by index

Tags: c++, c++14

In C++14, is there any sequence container which contains elements in sorted order(like sets) and can be accessed by indexes(like vectors)?

The requirement is to find the kth smallest element in the given array of integers and even some elements need to be updated, due to which the kth smallest element will keep changing.

E.g. a={1,2,3,4,5,6},k=3

if a[4] is updated with value 0, then a={0,1,2,3,4,6}, so kth smallest element=2.

Comment: Do you need it need it to allow duplicate values?

Comment: Also, do you want the entire collection to be sorted all the time, or just the kth element to be in the right position?